# Understand Code Linux Device Driver m25p80.c

Tags: c, linux, embedded, linux-device-driver, spi

I am working on an embedded device. At the moment I want to try to use another flash memory than the soldered one.
So I looked in the code of **m25p80.c** what can be compatible but with more memory. In this file we find this structure

```
static const struct spi_device_id m25p_ids[]
```

Which has this declaration. Of course that is not all.

```
{ "en25f32", INFO(0x1c3116, 0, 64 * 1024,  64, SECT_4K) },
{ "en25p32", INFO(0x1c2016, 0, 64 * 1024,  64, 0) },
{ "en25p64", INFO(0x1c2017, 0, 64 * 1024, 128, 0) },
{ "en25q64", INFO(0x1c3017, 0, 64 * 1024, 128, SECT_4K) },
```

Above in the code of m25p80.c we also find the definition of the macro **INFO**

```
#define INFO(_jedec_id, _ext_id, _sector_size, _n_sectors, _flags)  \
    ((kernel_ulong_t)&(struct flash_info) {             \
        .jedec_id = (_jedec_id),                \
        .ext_id = (_ext_id),                    \
        .sector_size = (_sector_size),              \
        .n_sectors = (_n_sectors),              \
        .page_size = 256,                   \
        .flags = (_flags),                  \
    })
```

Now I want to understand what some values mean, because I only understood few. For example for one type

```
 { "en25p64", INFO(0x1c2017, 0, 64 * 1024, 128, 0) },
```

- **INFO**  (above macro)
- **0x1c2017** (this I understood is a special ID for chip. It is helpful for the system to recognize the flash at boot time)
- **0** ( Another Id. May be not important)
- **64 * 1024**  (I have no idea what is this because in datasheet chip number of sectors is 2048 but not 65536)
- **128** (in datasheet this is correct with block number but here it is called *page size*)
- **0** (Flags, also please explain. What does SECT_4K or 0 for memory mean)

**Additional Question.**

Can the driver m25p80 handle flash SPI above 256Mb (4 address byte)? If not, which driver should I use?

Comment: "64 * 1024": How about this being the memory size in KiB? For other fields: check the definition of that struct type. For the rest: how about just reading the driver code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talking about `M25P80`

```
{ "m25p80",  INFO(0x202014,  0,  64 * 1024,  16, 0) },
```

Form datasheet page 6

> It is organized as 16 sectors, each containing 256 pages. Each page is 256
>   bytes wide

Then third parameter `64*1024` is `65536` that, as described, equal to `256pages x 256bytes`

About flags you can see values in `spi-nor.c`

```
#define SECT_4K                 0x01    /* SPINOR_OP_BE_4K works uniformly */
#define SPI_NOR_NO_ERASE        0x02    /* No erase command needed */
#define SST_WRITE               0x04    /* use SST byte programming */
#define SPI_NOR_NO_FR           0x08    /* Can't do fastread */
#define SECT_4K_PMC             0x10    /* SPINOR_OP_BE_4K_PMC works uniformly */
#define SPI_NOR_DUAL_READ       0x20    /* Flash supports Dual Read */
#define SPI_NOR_QUAD_READ       0x40    /* Flash supports Quad Read */
#define SPI_NOR_DDR_QUAD_READ   0x80    /* Flash supports DDR Quad Read */
```

**EDIT**

About 4 address wide chips, as you can see in `m25p80 driver probe` function, the `spi_nor_scan` is called. That function checks if the size of flash is bigger than `0x1000000` (16MegaBytes). If yes set `addr_width = 4` ancd checks other stuff to understand how to drive the device: eg. call `set_4byte` function that allow 4 byte address mode.

Comment: Ok this is correct, also for en25p64. Than You. And What about 4 byte adres in this driver ?

Comment: I'm not getting you. m25p80 is a 8 MegaBits memory that is 1MegaByte. Address MAX is 0xFFFFF.

Comment: @Mbded I edit the post to try to answer you about 4 address wide size

Comment: Great.  Now I understand this issue. Thank You for all reply

Comment: @Mbded You're welcome. Check as answered then, to close the post.